# How can I Get command exit code executed with Testcontainers?

Tags: docker-java, testcontainers

Using `GenericContainer#execInContainer` I can only get stdout or stderr.

Is there any way to get **exit code** of executed command?

I can't rely on the presence of text in stderr. The application I execute prints some info to stderr but exits with code 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`execInContainer` is just a shortcut to `execCreateCmd/execStartCmd` from docker-java. Unfortunately, their API doesn't provide a way to get the exit code.

But you can make use of built-in shell functionality and just return the code as part of stdout/stderr:

```
$ sh -c 'false; echo "ExitCode=$?"'
ExitCode=1
```

where `false` is your command

Comment: Here's a [gist implementing this solution](https://gist.github.com/dnault/01f9e4459a558d7c0928da33b6652a9d). Would it make sense to include something like this in Testcontainers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inspectExecCmd(execId)` to get information about the executed command, and also you can get exit code from the response of `inspectExecCmd`